# Find most recent donation excluding funds beginning with X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I'm trying to grab the gift date of the most recent donation (in $USD) to my organization that has a fund ID not beginning in X (those are Canadian donations).  Here's the code (in the controller) that I've used to pull out the gift date of the most recent overall donation, but it's a Canadian gift (fund_id = XP05).  How do I get the most recent donation with a fund ID not beginning with an X?

```
@income_batch = Gift.between(Date.today - 2.weeks, Date.today, :field => :gift_date).order('gift_date DESC').first.gift_date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `fund_id` is a string field within your `gifts` table, you can use `not like`:

```
Gift.where("fund_id not like 'X%").between....
```

You should also avoid using an `_id` postfix on fields unless they're foreign keys, as Rails convention dictates that `_id` is specific for this purpose.

---

If `fund_id` **is** a foreign key, and you have a `belongs_to :fund` inside your `Gift` model, you can use `joins` and `not like`:

```
Gift.joins(:fund).where("funds.name not like 'X%").between....
```

This assumes that the field within the `funds` table is called `name`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly!  Needed to an a single quote after the X% to read ... like 'X%'").between... but it did exactly what I wanted it to do.  And I appreciate your thoughts on the postfix.